# Strange repositioning using repaint();

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I have a JSlider in a JPanel that return me a value of R-G-B .
I create it, in the Costructor of  JPanel. I draw in same Panel (using paintComponent) a little circle, and I change his color using the Slider. I want that the color change in contemporany of slider shift.
So, i use the method repaint.. Next to Panel there is another Panel, with two button.. If I use method repaint in first panel , the buttons of second panel duplicated in the topLeft of First Panel. Why? Thank's you.

First Panel:

```
public class OptionsPanel extends JPanel {


static JSlider RBG = new JSlider(0,255);
OptionsPanel(){

this.setVisible(false);
this.setSize(350,1000);
this.setLayout(null);
this.setBackground(new Color(200,200,0));
Main.f1.add(this); 



 RBG.setVisible(true);
 RBG.setSize(255,50);
 RBG.setLocation(30,240);


 this.add(RBG);



LotL lotl = new LotL();
Button save = new Button("Save");

save.setVisible(true);
save.setSize(100,40);
save.setLayout(null);
save.setLocation(60,300);
save.addActionListener(lotl); 
save.setBackground(Color.yellow);
save.identificatore=3;
this.add(save);







  }


  boolean draw=false;

  @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){



 g.drawOval(50,100,70,70);

 g.setColor(new Color(RBG.getValue(),180,200));
 g.fillOval(50,100,70,70);


 repaint();




}
}
```

Second Panel:

```
public class FirstPanel extends JPanel{
FirstPanel(){

this.setVisible(true);
this.setSize(1000,1000);
this.setLayout(null);
this.setBackground(new Color(255,200,180)); 
Main.f1.add(this);

Button start = new Button("Start Game!");


Button options = new Button("Options");
LotL LotL = new LotL();  



start.setVisible(true);
start.setSize(200,80);
start.setLayout(null);
start.setLocation(400,450);
start.addActionListener(LotL); 
start.setBackground(Color.green);
start.identificatore=1;
this.add(start);

options.setVisible(true);
options.setSize(200,70);
options.setLayout(null);
options.setLocation(400,550);
options.addActionListener(LotL); 
options.setBackground(Color.green);
options.identificatore=2;
this.add(options);

}


}
```

Comment: You're using Button instead of JButton.  Provide a minimal, complete, and **runnable** example of your problem, and you might attract more help.

Comment: `save.identificatore=3;` What is that `Button`? Is this a custom class of yours? What does it extend?

Comment: Sorry you have reason Button is a extended class of JButton i  add only ad attribute 'id' identificatore.. Thank's you MadProgrammer! Now all works!

Answer (score 2):

You've broken the paint chain...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    g.drawOval(50,100,70,70);

    g.setColor(new Color(RBG.getValue(),180,200));
    g.fillOval(50,100,70,70);


    repaint();

}
```

`Graphics` is a shared resource, which gets passed to ALL the components that are painted during a given paint cycle.

One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting, but filling with the components background color.

You MUST call `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawOval(50,100,70,70);

    g.setColor(new Color(RBG.getValue(),180,200));
    g.fillOval(50,100,70,70);
}
```

Also, there is never any need for `paintComponent` to be `public`, no one should ever be calling directly and NEVER modify the state of a component from within any paint method which may trigger a repaint, you will get yourself into a infinite loop which will eventually consume your CPU and make you computer unusable.

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

You should also avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify